# div check box to be dimmed on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I found this code on another post on this website what makes it so you can click anywhere in the div and it ticks the check box for you.

Below is the code that I found however I have changed it by giving it an `id`

```
<label for="cb">
     <div id="clickablediv">
         <input name="cb" id="cb" type="checkbox">
     </div>
</label>
```

[Link to original question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584239/click-on-a-div-to-toggle-a-checkbox-inside-of-it-using-javascript)

I would like to extend this question/answer by adding some java script to it so when the div is clicked it fades out the div a little bit so you can tell it has been clicked and if it is clicked again then it goes to its original looks. I am thinking maybe a grey color added with a transparency so you can still see the div underneath once it has been clicked.

Here is a [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/4xByj/) with the `HTML` and some `CSS` to give the div some content what will be dulled out on click.

I am using `jquery 1.11.0` on my site at the moment so if `jquery` is used could you please make sure it works with `1.11.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the opacity fade with animation: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/aZK5X/2/)

```
$('#clickablediv').click(function () {
    if ($(this).find('#cb').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0.5
        }, 250);
    } else {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 250);
    }
});
```

Comment: I believe this is the perfect answer. I will just double check it within my actual files but it looks very promising. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use some CSS3 transitions to fade the color and jquery's `.is(":checked")` to accomplish this EDIT: didn't see the part about clicking the div, updated fiddle and code

```
$("#clickablediv").click(function(){
 if($("#cb").is(":checked")){
   $("#clickablediv").css({"background":"rgba(0,0,0,.4)"});
 }else{
   $("#clickablediv").css({"background":"#0b61a4"});
 }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4xByj/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had to preposition the label so the whole div is clickable but it works great except I would like to have the grey get put onto of the div and not having the div change color as the div it self with have 2 others divs in it that both have different colors. Changing the div background color will not have an effect I think as it will be hidden behind the other 2 divs that are placed within that one

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand but you should be able to accomplish that with the code I provided. Just add CSS transitions to the div you do want to target and update which div you target on click

Comment: that is ok. I believe @tomanow has just answered it perfectly.

Comment: @Luke understand if you animate the opacity of that container, anything inside will have the same opacity applied to it (note that in tomanow 's answer the checkbox fades out too). If that is what you are going for then fine, but otherwise you need to use `rgba` and css transitions

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple `.click` event handler checking for the state of the checkbox:

```
$("#clickablediv").click(function(){
    if($(this).children("#cb")[0].checked){
        $(this).css({backgroundColor:"#389BE8"})   
    }else{        
        $(this).css({backgroundColor:"#0b61a4"}) 
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/4xByj/1/) illustrating answer.

Definitely consider using CSS3 transitions, as jmore009 suggested, in order to animate the color change.

Comment: is there a way to put the grey over the top of the div as the div it self will have 2 divs within it what both are different colors so changing the div color wouldn't have a visual effect

Comment: @Luke: definitely. Just a question, does the main div have a definite width and height, or do they change, because the implementation would be slightly different.

Comment: Thank you JCO for your time. Tomanow has answered it perfectly but your method is also good except I am unable to use that method with the code I am using as I have multiply divs within the div that will be dulled out. If you click Tomanow's jsfiddle you will see what I was looking for. Thank you once again

Comment: @Luke: I am glad you got the answer you were looking for!

Comment: I am not sure if you are about but I was wondering if you would be able to help me some more with this problem. I do not really want to make another question but I will do if I need to. the div is duplicated because of an array i call for different information and with 2 divs with the same id the 1st div is the only one that gets clicked when I need it to elim the div that is clicked on. I think you might get what i mean by this http://jsfiddle.net/6as7b/

Answer (score 0):

you can set opacity of yur checkbox to 1, then use .animate() to animate it to fade out like this:

```
$('#cb').animate({opacity:0.3}, 500);
```

Then set a variable to keep the state of the checkbox clicked or not.
JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4xByj/5/
It is compatible with jquery 1.11.0