# IE7 object expected

Tags: javascript, html

Strange behaviour by IE 7, all other browsers work fine obviously!

If I click the checkbox it returns: object expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/EnYVZ/1/

Any ideas why?

Code:

```
<div class='tile' onclick=checkbox('95991285')>
<label for='95991285'>
<div>
<input style='vertical-align:middle' type='checkbox' name='frnd[]' value='95991285' id='95991285' checked='checked' />
<img style='vertical-align:middle' src='http://s13.postimage.org/je9k86un7/img.jpg'>
<p>full name</p>
</div>
</label>
</div>​
```

Comment: It fails in all browsers because you simply don't have function called "checkbox". This is not native JavaScript function.

Comment: How many browsers did you check with? Firefox says: "checkbox is not defined". Is that working fine?

Comment: Seriously now, what are you trying to achieve with this code? Maybe we can help. Maybe we can suggest using a `<label>`.

Comment: add javascript code to jsfiddle :/ have you tried `onclick="checkbox('1000015175634')"` ?

Comment: an ID can not be numeric either!

Comment: @hb40 I did try that actually, but it didn't make a difference. All browsers apparently apply the same kind of tolerance there.

Comment: Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/), there are some obvious errors that it would pick up.

Comment: guys I pasted only the portion of the code that I tought was producing the error. Now the full code was updated in the question + you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/EnYVZ/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I referenced to this thread:

[How do I make a checkbox toggle from clicking on the text label as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123/how-do-i-make-a-checkbox-toggle-from-clicking-on-the-text-label-as-well)

my original code:

```
<div class='tile' onclick=checkbox('95991285')>
<label for='95991285'>
<div>
<input style='vertical-align:middle' type='checkbox' name='frnd[]' value='95991285' id='95991285' checked='checked' />
<img style='vertical-align:middle' src='http://s13.postimage.org/je9k86un7/img.jpg'>
<p>full name</p>
</div>
</label>
</div>​
```

I removed this: `onclick=checkbox('95991285')`

My code was the result of taking more sources and joining them together.
It working with all the browsers, except IE 7 and lower and I wanted to understand why.

I am a beginner in javascript and I assumed onclick checkbox was a native function, but it's not.

working code:

```
<div class='tile'>
<label for='95991285'>
<div>
<input style='vertical-align:middle' type='checkbox' name='frnd[]' value='95991285' id='95991285' checked='checked' />
<img style='vertical-align:middle' src='http://s13.postimage.org/je9k86un7/img.jpg'>
<p>full name</p>
</div>
</label>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a checkbox function defined.  You're trying to call a function with this statement

```
checkbox('1000015175634')
```

But that function does not exist.

There are a host of other minor problems as well that could probably be helped by running the code through a validator...but that's the big one.

The code should probably look something like this:

```
<div class="tile" onclick="checkboxAction('a1000015175634')">     
    <input type="checkbox" value="a1000015175634" id="a1000015175634" checked="checked" />     
    <p>name</p>
</div>

<script>
    function checkboxAction(inputBox) {
        // something with inputBox
    }
</script>​
```

What exactly is this supposed to be doing?

Comment: Opening curly brackets should *always* go on the line containing the function statement in JavaScript.

Comment: @danwellman Why?  (I'm not saying they shouldn't...I'm just not sure what the rationale is.)

Comment: @danwellman Nevermind...a quick search turned up the answer pretty quickly. http://encosia.com/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/  Now fixed.